# BlueJ User Input Code Never Compiles

Tags: input, compilation, compiler-errors, bluej

I have a small piece of code that should compile and allow the user to input a figure in the terminal window ( I am using Blue J).

However, while it does 'compile', I can never open, view or interact with the terminal window. I am met with a red "object box" instead.

I have been trying for a while to get around this problem and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Here is the code used:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PartA
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input your message: "); //this is the user promot
        String message = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(message);

    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the answer to this problem since posting.

While I was clicking on new PartA() to view the program in the terminal window, this only created an object (the red box). By clicking on public static void main(String[] args) (essentially a method as opposed to an object) I was able to view, and interact with the terminal window.